# backtracking inside the negative lookahead

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I want to find how the backtracking works inside the negative lookahead. like in ...

```
     ^(?!.*some My Words$).*$
```

how far the the regex engine will try the first `.*`. I am testing `somewhere awesome My Words`. Which I expect should be rejected, but not. So how the backtracking is working here and how this is happening?

Comment: Ok... I think I used double spaces in the input string..

Comment: Try your regexp wit phrase "dfjsdlfj skldfjsd klfjsdklf jsdlsdkfjsdl jsdfkl", and you'll have a match, too :).

Comment: yes that is expected to be matched.. only rejection for the string ending with `..some My Words`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample example would be rejected for the above regex.

`.*` eats everything and reaches to the end. i.e after last `s`.Then it backtracks 1 by 1 till it matches `some My Words`.

With `.*?` it would match till the first `some My Words`

---

`.*?` is better than `.*` but performance gain would be significant only for **large** strings

Comment: Ok.. now I think I will never forget how these expressions work.. and the sample had double spaces that was causing the problem .. I am testing here.. http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/dotnet/index.html